# Custom Login Form is not working using Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am learning Spring MVC and trying to implement spring security in my application. I have created custom login and trying to login using custom login form. While I am running application Login page is appearing properly but after entering the username and password it's not working. Submitting login form is calling controller action neither it's redirecting to any other page. I am not able to understand which configuration is required here.

> **SecurityConfig.Java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception 
    {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("test").password("test").roles("admin");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/loginPage")
        .permitAll();
    }
}
```

> **SecurityWebAppInitializer.java**

```
public class SecurityWebAppInitializer extends 
AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

}
```

> **AuthController.java**

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/loginPage" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String loginPage(ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("user",new User());
    return "Login";
}

@RequestMapping(value = { "/success/login" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String login(@ModelAttribute("user") @Validated User user, BindingResult result, Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
    System.out.println("Login is called.");

    return "UserDashboard";
 }
```

> **login.jsp**

```
<form:form method="post" action="./success/login" id="login" 
modelAttribute="user" role="form" style="display: block;">
    <div class="form-group">
        <form:input name= "username" path="username" id="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" tabindex="1" class="form-control"/>
        <form:errors path="username" cssStyle="color: red;"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <form:input name="password" path="password" id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" tabindex="2" class="form-control"/>
        <form:errors path="password" cssStyle="color: red;"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group text-center">
        <input type="checkbox" tabindex="3" class="" name="remember" id="remember">
        <label for="remember"> Remember Me</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                <input type="submit" name="login-submit" id="submit" tabindex="4" class="form-control btn btn-login" value="Log In">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <a href="https://phpoll.com/recover" tabindex="5" class="forgot-password">Forgot Password?</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form:form>
```

So my login page is coming properly but after entering username password is not working. I dont know my project structure is responsible for errors or not because sometimes after clicking on login it will redirect to resource.

Answer (score 3):

...CREDIT GOES TO CHAD DARBY...

The root cause is because the Maven project was generated by an archetype. Unfortunately, the archetype generates legacy config files. As a result, the web project is based on an older version of the Servlet 2.3. The old version of the Servlet 2.3 spec does not support features required for Spring Security 5. That is the reason your app did not initially work.

There are a number of ways to resolve this. I'll use one of the simpler techniques below.

1. Delete the web.xml file

Next we will need to manually edit an Eclipse configuration file.

2. Right-click project, select Properties > Resource. At the far right of Location field is a button that will open the project directory on your file system.
3. Exit Eclipse (you will need to exit because we are updating eclipse project configs)
4. On your file system, move into the .settings directory for your project
5. Using a text editor, edit the file: org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml
6. Change the jst.web version to 4.0. For example your file should look like

```
<faceted-project>
<fixed facet="wst.jsdt.web"/>
<installed facet="wst.jsdt.web" version="1.0”/>
<installed facet="jst.web" version="4.0"/>
<installed facet="java" version="1.8”/>
</faceted-project>
```

save the file

7. Start Eclipse

Now let's Refresh and Clean

8. Right-click your project and select Refresh
9. In the Server's tab in Eclipse, Stop the Tomcat server
10. Expand your Tomcat server and remove all existing applications
11. Right-click the server and select "Clean..."
12. Right-click the server again and select "Clean Tomcat Work Directory..."

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to send an object or validate the password since Spring takes care of that for you nor redirect. If you wish to redirect them after they successfully authenticated, then you can add `.defaultSuccessUrl(url)` in your configuration and it redirects them to that page automatically. Also, the method has to be `POST` and the action must be `login` - these 2 requirements are a MUST. Here is a tutorial by Baeldung http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-login or you can follow this one https://github.com/AritonV10/spring-security-demo

Answer (score 0):

This is how I resolve the issue.

Step 1. Delete web.xml file.

Step 2. Click on your project folder.

```
    to Window > Show View > Navigator

    Go to Navigator and expand the .settings folder
```

Step 3. Change the dynamic web module version in this line to 4.0 -

```
<installed facet="jst.web" version="4.0"/>
```

Step 4. Right-click on the project (in the Project Explorer panel).

```
    Select Maven » Update Project (or press Alt+F5)
```